# Why does the Z transform represent a delay?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, control-theory, signal-processing, z-transform

I'm studying the Z-transform. I recently did by hand the Z transform of an discrete impulse delayed  $\mathcal{z}\{\delta[n-k]\} = z^{-k}$

I get that this means that any signal can be represented as a linear combination of powers of $z^{-k}$. And this clearly has a direct link to the z transform of a diference for solving diference equations.

What I cannot grasp is why the use of an abritrary complex number Z in the convolution gives that particular result $\mathcal{z}\{\delta[n-k]\} = z^{-k}$
for a delay .

Comment: What do you mean by "the use of an abritrary complex number Z in the convolution gives that particular result"? The result that you mention follows immediately from the definition, so why should we look for an explanation?

Comment: I think your question is more like "why does Z-transform represent anything?". Why the use of an arbitrary complex number - or rather complex rational polynomials - represent a function in time?

Comment: Yeah, why the arbitraty selection of a complex number in the form of Z^k as an input of a discrete system is a powerfull analysis tool ? Why do we chose Z^-k as the basis of our signal space ?